# trigonometry - identities and formula, proving

Tags: trigonometry

Prove:

$$\sin(x) - \sin(x) \cos^2(x)  =  \sin^3(x).$$

I swear it is easy, but I don't know what I'm forgetting to look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\cos^2(x) = 1-\sin^2(x)$ from the Pythagorean identity. If you substitute this into your expression, what do you get?

Comment: I understand what u did there, but I'm still getting a wrong squared number next to sin? Is there a certain order it has to be worked out afterwards?

Comment: $$\sin(x) - \sin(x)(1-\sin^2(x)) = \sin(x) - \sin(x) - (-\sin^3(x)).$$ Did you forget to properly distribute the negative?

Comment: Close, forgot to times - sin(x) it by the whole substituted part.  THANK YOU, you make me laugh at my own idiotic mistakes, hahaha

Comment: Ahh. Glad you figured it out :) It's an easy mistake to make. I even make these mistakes from time to time.